# Repository Creation in Emacs Git

Tags: git, version-control, emacs24

How could I create a repository in Emacs git, is there a Emacs command?

Just installed git.el in site-lisp directory but can't find this info anywhere.

Already managed to use a ready git repository, but couldn't create one from within Emacs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can i create a repository in Emacs git, is there a Emacs command?

It doesn't look `git.el` supports this. [It is focused around its `git-status` command](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/tree/contrib/emacs/README?id=HEAD), which prompts for a root directory and complains when you give it one that isn't already initialized.

However, Emacs' [built-in VC mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Introduction-to-VC.html#Introduction-to-VC) will do this with its `vc-create-repo` command:

> Create an empty repository in the current directory.

Make sure to `(require 'vc)` somewhere, `cd` to the target directory (or visit a file in it), then `M-x vc-create-repo RET`. VC Mode supports many version control backends, so when prompted, type `git` (tab-completion is available here).

Finally, there is an *excellent* Git mode called [Magit](http://magit.vc/) that also supports creating repositories. If given a directory that isn't a repository, `magit-status` command will ask if you want to create one. Magit is available via [MELPA](http://melpa.org/#/).

Comment: Ok, already noticed the lack of some git functions in git.el. Now can't find proper documentation about it! Which are the available commands and how to execute them? Could find in documentation only about U to revert and C for commiting.

Comment: The only official documentation I was able to find is [its `README`](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/tree/contrib/emacs/README?id=HEAD). I found reading [the source](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/git/git.git/tree/contrib/emacs/git.el?id=HEAD) to be more helpful. You might also have luck pressing the `?` key, which might give you more information about its keybindings. Once again, I do urge you to try VC mode or Magit, both of which are very good in different ways.

Comment: Pressing "?" is right what i was looking for, just a description of available commands. Now thinking on how i could add this command listing into git.el README file.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should use [RCS](http://www.gnu.org/software/rcs/) instead of Git, http://www.gnu.org/software/rcs/.

First, install it via `$ sudo apt install rcs`

Then add the following into `.emacs` init file:

`(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d/lisp/") 
(load "rcs")`

Once done, you may use it via `CTRL + v + v`.